# Is true that these two topologies are finer than the standard topology on line and are not comparable

Tags: general-topology

I was asked to exibe two topologies non comparable and finer than the standard topology of line. I stated:

1. The Sorgenfrey line $\mathbb{R}_l$ and
2. The topology whose base is defined as:

$$\{(a,b) : a < b, a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(a,b)\cap \mathbb{Q} : a < b, a, b\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Is this right?

Comment: I've never heard the Sorgenfrey line called the "longe line" before. What's the source of this name? It sounds a lot like the "long line", which is something else entirely...

Comment: sorry, @AlexKruckman, it was confusing from my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. For the Sorgenfrey line, note that its base sets are the half open intervals $[a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb R$, and we have
$$
 (a,b) = \bigcup_n \left[a+\frac{1}{n}, b\right)
$$
hence it contains every set open in the standard topology. For your second example it refines the standard topology by construction, and as every set open in the standard topology contains some irrational number, the refinement is proper.

But one more obvious topology might be $(\mathbb R, \mathcal P(\mathbb R))$, i.e. the discrete topology where every subset is open. This refines each topology, in particualr the standard one.

Comment: but note, these two i cited are non comparable with each other, right?

Comment: No. As every half open interval contains irrationals, the base sets consisting just of rationals are not open in the Sorgenfrey line topology, hence the Sorgenfrey topology is not a refinement of your second topology. Conversely, the half open interval $[0,1)$ is not open in your second topology. For if it would, we could replace every interval $(a,b) \cap \mathbb Q \subseteq [0,1)$ by $(a,b)$ as it would also be included, giving that $[a,b)$ would be open in the standard topology, which it is not.

Comment: so these two are not comparable, thats right?

Comment: Neither is a refinement of the other, so in that sense they are not comparable.

Comment: THANK YOU! Really, thank you!

Comment: could I argue that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is finer than the standard topology since for each open $(a,b)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, I can find an basis element of Sorgenfrey line contained on $(a,b)?$ 
I could this as follows: Take $c = (b-a)/2.$ Then $a < c < b.$ So, $[c,b) \subset (a,b).$

Comment: @Leonardo: No, you have to show that $(a,b)$ is actually open in $\Bbb R_\ell$. You could do this by showing that for each $x\in(a,b)$ there is a basic open set in the Sorgenfrey line that contains $x$ and is a subset of $(a,b)$; the obvious one to use is $[x,b)$.

Comment: Yes, that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Call the second topology $R_Q.$ There are many ways to show that $R_l$ and $R_Q$ are incomparable.

(1).  No member of the given base $B$ for $R_Q$ has a $<$-least member. And $[0,1)$ is $R_l$-open. If $[0,1)$ were $R_Q$-open then $0\in b\subset [0,1)$ for some $b\in B.$ But then  $\min b=0,$ a contradiction. Therefore $[0,1)\in R_l$  \  $R_Q.$

(2).  Every member of the standard base for $R_l$ is an infinite $<$-convex set. And $Q\cap (0,1)$ is $R_Q$-open. So if $Q\cap (0,1)$ were $R_l$-open it would have an infinite $<$-convex subset. Therefore $Q\cap (0,1)\in R_Q$ \ $R_l.$

Comment: What is an "infinite $<$-convex set"? As far as I know a set $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is convex iff with two points, it contains the line segment connecting those two points, but cannot connect that to your statement...

Comment: @Stefan . I mean an infinite convex set.